# Implement javascript promise or async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, ejs, xml2js

I am on the newer side to programming; the concept of promises and async/await functionality is something I have had a hard time wrapping my head around. But I know that it is something I should be utilizing in this case.

Background: Building a prototype-banking application with Node, Express, XML2js npm package to parse the XML data that I am working with, XMLhttpRequest, and EJS for templating.
I have this get route in my server.js:

```js
    const parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
    
    app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
     makeCall(`<root>
      <slipped>
        <mail>
          <alike>-1845676614.3625278</alike>
          <paid>uncle</paid>
          <kill>something</kill>
          <name>Stephen<name>
          <men>such</men>
          <firm>rubbed</firm>
          <using>yesterday</using>
        </mail>
      </slipped>
      <pour>-1247721160</pour>
      <poet>language</poet>
      <sets>-1907281866</sets>
      <treated>proper</treated>
      <judge>781679047</judge>
     </root>`)
    //Putting the format of the XML *response* above, to show what I am rendering from
      setTimeout(function () {
        res.render('home.ejs', {
          name: dataList[0].root.slipped.mail.name
        })
      }, 1000);
    })
```

I am wanting to have the app wait and finish makeCall(), *before* home.ejs gets rendered. If I don't wait, then it will propagate the old value instead. It does work how it is now, but I believe there is a much more efficient way of doing this.

**How can I rewrite the above logic using promises or async/await behavior instead of setTimeout?**

For reference, the makeCall():

```js
    const makeCall = (call) => {
      myRequest.open('POST', 'http://111.222.3.444:55555')
      myRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      myRequest.send(call)
      myRequest.onload = () => {
        if (myRequest.status === 200) {
          parseString(myRequest.responseText, (err, result) => {
            dataList.unshift(result)
          })
        } else {
          console.log('Something went wrong, status code: ' + myRequest.status)
        }
      }
    }
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return a promise in makeCall so you can wait for it in your main method. Here is an example

```
const makeCall = (call) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    myRequest.open('POST', 'http://111.222.3.444:55555')
    myRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    myRequest.send(call)
    myRequest.onload = () => {
      if (myRequest.status === 200) {
        parseString(myRequest.responseText, (err, result) => {
          dataList.unshift(result);
          resolve();
        })
      } else {
        console.log('Something went wrong, status code: ' + myRequest.status)
        reject();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Then you can wait for it to finish to continue in your main method. You can do that by using promises like:

```
makeCal(...)
.then(() => your_success_logic)
.catch((e) => your_error_logic);
```

Or you can use async/await like this:

```
app.get('/home', async (req, res) => {
    await makeCal(...);
    res.render('home.ejs', {
      name: dataList[0].root.slipped.mail.name
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make something asynchronous by using the `new Promise` constructor. It takes a function with two callbacks (resolve,reject). If it fails, reject it. If it's successful you can use resolve. Node 10 and above you can use the `async` function like so and use the `await` keyword to wait until a asynchronous function resolves or rejects before moving foward.

```
const parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
    
   app.get('/home', async (req, res) => {
    await makeCall(`<root>
     <slipped>
       <mail>
         <alike>-1845676614.3625278</alike>
         <paid>uncle</paid>
         <kill>something</kill>
         <name>Stephen<name>
         <men>such</men>
         <firm>rubbed</firm>
         <using>yesterday</using>
       </mail>
     </slipped>
     <pour>-1247721160</pour>
     <poet>language</poet>
     <sets>-1907281866</sets>
     <treated>proper</treated>
     <judge>781679047</judge>
    </root>`)

   //Putting the format of the XML *response* above, to show what I am rendering from
    res.render('home.ejs', {
      name: dataList[0].root.slipped.mail.name
    })
   }) 

const makeCall = (call) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    myRequest.open('POST', 'http://111.222.3.444:55555')
    myRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    myRequest.send(call)
    myRequest.onload = () => {
      if (myRequest.status === 200) {
        parseString(myRequest.responseText, (err, result) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err)
          } else {
            dataList.unshift(result)
            resolve()
          }
        })
      } else {
        console.log('Something went wrong, status code: ' + myRequest.status)
        reject(new Error(''Something went wrong, status code: ' + myRequest.status'))
      }
    }
  })
}
```